# Submit button with multiple zones on page

Tags: java, html, forms, tapestry

I have a page with a form submission that contains two zones. When the edit selected user button is clicked the form submits  and thus refreshing the page. Everything works as intended other than the need to go back to this page where the values are populated. I need for the page to not refresh/submit when Edit Selected User is clicked. AFAIK I cannot make it a button as buttons are not valid tapestry components.

```
<!-- USER EDIT BEGINS -->
<t:zone t:id="editUserZone" id="editUserZone"> 
<form t:id="editUserForm" id="editUserForm" t:type="form"> 

                    <div id="editUserHeader">
                        Edit an Existing User
                    </div>
                    <div id="findUser">
                        <label>Search For User to Edit: </label>
                        <t:textfield id="editUser" t:id="editUser"  /> <input type ="button"  id="change"  
        onclick="window.open('${childWindowLink}','Ratting','width=850,height=350,left=150,top=200,toolbar=0,status=0,menubar=no,resizable=no')"  
        value="Search Users" />
                <t:submit t:id="searchUsersEdit" id="searchUsersEdit" value="Edit Selected User" />
        <br/><br/>


<h5>User Permissions</h5><br/>

                    </div>

<t:zone t:id="editRefresh" id="editRefresh" t:update="show"> 
                        ${editMessages}

     //FORM FIELDS ETC HERE

       <input t:type="submit" t:id="editUserButton" value="Edit User"/> 

                                  </div>
                         </t:zone>
                    </form>
                </t:zone>
```

I need the form to submit only when the Edit User button at the bottom is clicked. Is this just a tapestry quirk or is there a way around this that doesn't involve redesigning the page?

Comment: I did not look at your problem in detail, but if you are doing your zones properly this should be a walk in the park with Tapestry. At a first glance your problem seems to be that your zone is in a form and your "Edit Selected User" is a submit, which will submit the form no matter what. If you haven't already, look at [this demo](http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/ajax/eventlink) which might be doing just what you need.

Comment: I will take a look, unfortunately my hands are tied with the submit on 'Edit Selected User' as a button is not a valid tapestry component to execute the block of code I need. This demo looks like it cold be promising. Thank you @SantiBailors

Comment: You are welcome, and I think you are off-track with the "a button is not a valid tapestry component" thing. Most likely that demo will show you the Tapestry way to do this (which is really easy), and if that's not the case you will certainly find there another demo that does exactly what you need. BTW I recommend to bookmark that jumpstart link because it's gold if you use Tapestry, it has a lot of great demos.

Comment: @SantiBailors the link was most useful, however with an eventlink the issue that arises is that the value of a text field cannot be passed (to my knowledge) so it is not a viable solution in this instance. To achieve this I think the multiple form demo on the link you supplied may work provided I split the page into two distinct forms and use some javascript/jquery to display the second upon submit.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<input type ="button"  id="change"  
    onclick="window.open('${childWindowLink}','Ratting','width=850,height=350,left=150,top=200,toolbar=0,status=0,menubar=no,resizable=no')"  
    value="Search Users" />
```

use

```
<button type="button" id="change" onclick="window.open('${childWindowLink}','Ratting','width=850,height=350,left=150,top=200,toolbar=0,status=0,menubar=no,resizable=no')">Search Users</button>
```

Make sure to use type="button" attribute. Or you can use link and stylize it as button.